# Android app relaunches on Launcher icon selection - user is logged out

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

I have an app with a login screen which takes the user to a splash screen. If the user navigates away from the app and then clicks on the launcher icon again, he has to log back in again. This only happens if I install the app on the device using the apk file. If I run it in debug mode with eclipse connected to the device, then this does not happen. During debug mode, if I click the launcher after navigating away from the app, I get back to my splash screen which is the expected behaviour.

The problem is that I don't know what's going on if I install the app on the device using the apk file. I cant access the logs or debug. The splash screen doesn't auto-logout on resume.

Does anyone know why this happens or what iIcan do to further investigate?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [This Page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html).

What i think may be happening is during the onPause or onStop method something is being triggered which causes your session information to be disregarded. Whether the Pause or Stop is called is a matter of resources available and may have a different result in debug and normal running mode.

I would suggest adding these functions to your activity, see which are called (as well as their Create and Resume partners) and determine whether this is the cause of your problems.

I have personally had similar issues with resources being freed when the application loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

I guess by saying "when user navigates away" you mean that the user go to another app or do something else. So under that case `onPause()` will be called when your app is paused, and `onSaveInstanceState()` when your app is destroyed.

So you might want to perform your logout action *explicitly* in both `onPause()` and `onSaveInstanceState()`, so your app has a consistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I  did override the life cycle methods however this suggestion worked:

[App completely restarting when launched by icon press in launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126511/app-completely-restarting-when-launched-by-icon-press-in-launcher)

A simple device restart resolves the problem