# Android app restarts when opened by clicking app icon

Tags: android, android-activity, icons

Scenario :

I open my app by clicking icon, do something, navigate through activities, pause the app by clicking home button.

*Case 1:*

If I open my app by clicking icon again, the app restarts from the first activity.

*Case 2:*

If I open my app from recently open apps (in 4.0 by pressing menu button and selecting my app) it starts from the paused state.

I want the behavior 2 always to occur, don't want my app to restart every time when it is opened by clicking icon.

I have compared my manifest file with other apps and they are similar to mine, but behave differently (i.e like 2nd case which i want).

**Edit:**

This has been asked here : [App completely restarting when launched by icon press in launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126511/app-completely-restarting-when-launched-by-icon-press-in-launcher)

but no answers :(

Comment: you share your first Activity code here, because from that we found what is the problem behind that.

Comment: its a splash activity does not do anything except showing an image for 2 secs and then starting another activity

Comment: May be it has something to do with manifest file. can you post it?

Comment: If you don't have any problem than post splash Activity code here...

Comment: to @user3422577 your edit was rejected because it sounds too much like a comment you should post in the comments. I'll quote you: "*This is for first time when you install the application, if when you close the app in background and than work the behavior is same.*" But I don't even understand what you meant. Doesn't seem like you really read the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found it. I had set a flag `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in my *activity flag*. I deleted that code.

I also added `onsaveInstance` method to all the activities in my code and it's working now!

Thanks :)

Comment: You should accept your own answer, if this was the solution indeed.

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same problem; but I have not any launchMode flag anywhere. Could you elaborate a bit more on how you resolved using the `onSaveInstanceState` function? (I suppose you meant onSaveInstanceState )

Comment: It was actually not required. Its working for me even after I have deleted the onsaveInstance code.

Comment: In my case, I have it for the entire application tag in the manifest

Comment: Hi, the launchMode solved my problem. Recently, I have a webview. When I minimized the app and click the icon again, it somehow closed. This solved that. Thank you !!

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your launcher activity:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) {
    finish();
    return; 
}
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Comment: This does nothing. clicking on the icon will do nothing because of that finish() call

Answer (score 0):

In current activity set some image which needs to be displayed for 2 seconds like below.

```
ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
im.setImageResource(set your image);
setContentView(im);
intentMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
Handler x = new Handler();
x.postDelayed(new splashhandler(), 2000);
```

Then start your activity in the SplashHandler class (which implements runnable and call start activity in run method).

It will display your Splash screen for 2 seconds and start another activity.

Answer (score 0):

seems in AndroidManifest you kept your launch activity `android:launchMode="singleTask"`. remove this one from your launch activity will solve problem

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace you splash Activity code with this code..

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while (_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if (_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.toString();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    splashTread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```