# I need to minimize the android application on back button click

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to minimize the application when back button is pressed.

I use following code to catch hardware back button click event

---

help me with the code of minimize on back key pressed

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, keyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK;
    //minimize application
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think that you need to treat `back` event as `home` event. The code below is how I emulate `home` pressed when User press `back` button:

```
 public void minimizeApp() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Comment: i am new here.. help me how to?

Comment: In each answer, there's a tick (check) image below up/down vote. You can tick it (from gray -> green) to accept this answer to avoid anyone re-answer this question.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc ,if there is another app opened behind my app, on calling `minimizeApp()` it minimises all apps opened in background .How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 49):

This is a simple code to minimize the application

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

Comment: You saved me !
After a week looking for "releasing the foreground" I finally found your wonderfull answer. Which exactly respond to my question, even if it is not the same as this one.

Answer (score 8):

try this code, this will minimize Activity.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
     {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

or

If you want to close the activity use `this.finish()` method to close the current running activity. instead of `this.moveTaskToBack(true);`