# Open Splash activity once

Tags: android, android-activity

I am opening splash activity once, this is what i have done.

> ```
> public class StartupActivity extends Activity {
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
>                 .getDefaultSharedPreferences(StartupActivity.this);
>         String lang = settings.getString("opened", "");
>         if(opened.equals("1")
>         {
>         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
>         startActivity(i);
>         finish();
>         }else { //I am setting here  opened to 1 
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);} 
> }
> ```

Where does the problem lie? When I open the app first time, this activity shows setcontentview activity main, but second time user opens app it goes to secondactivity .But the problem is , for couple of milliseconds the second time  i open the app it is making it obvious  that splash activity is opening then closing  for couple of milliseconds.

Comment: After you opened the splash activity You didn't set the value as 1. `putString`

Comment: i have done that, thats not the issue at all.

Comment: You're launching the `Activity`; that's why it's showing. The `Activity`'s window is still going to load, even if you don't call `setContentView()`.

Comment: yes, how can i solve that thing?

Comment: Your screen will splash at anycost. Because it is the launcher activity in your application. Try to call super after checking prefereences . May reduce a millisecond. Note: In slower devices your application will show a black screen for some seconds

Comment: Where do you save "opened" parameter of preferences?

Comment: in the commented part, /I am setting here  opened to 1 .

Comment: You could create an `Activity` with a `NoDisplay` theme as the launch `Activity`, and decide in its `onCreate()` whether to start `StartupActivity` or `SecondActivity`.

Comment: @user3278732 even though you mentioned that you set value for "opened" but there is still high chance that you missed something there. can you put code for it. I just want to make sure you use apply() or commit()

Answer (score 0):

I believe your splash is the launcher activity of your application and what you are trying to do is , once you have launched the splash and passed the value to second activity then splash shouldn't show .
I saw a similar question long ago , check if it answers it

[App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes)