# Can Activity.getIntent() ever return null?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Can [`Activity.getIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) ever return `null`?

The documentation does not mention this as a possibility, so I am wondering if I have to check the result of `getIntent()` for `null` value before dereferencing it.

Comment: I guess this could also be rephrased as "Can an `Activity` ever be triggered in its normal lifecycle without an `Intent` being involved?"

Comment: no `getIntent` never returns null, since is the object you used to start the Activity

Comment: It can return null, but only if you set it to null in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 71):

**Yes, it can**,
but only in two cases:

**In activity constructor:** 
Intent set up in internal `attach` method, called from `Instrumentation` class:

```
public Activity newActivity(Class<?> clazz, Context context, 
        IBinder token, Application application, Intent intent, ActivityInfo info, 
        CharSequence title, Activity parent, String id,
        Object lastNonConfigurationInstance) throws InstantiationException, 
        IllegalAccessException {
    Activity activity = (Activity)clazz.newInstance();
    ActivityThread aThread = null;
    activity.attach(context, aThread, this, token, 0, application, intent,
            info, title, parent, id,
            (Activity.NonConfigurationInstances)lastNonConfigurationInstance,
            new Configuration(), null, null);
    return activity;
}
```

therefore intent is always null in constructor.

**After setIntent(null):**
It's possible to change intent from outside of activity with [`setIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent)).

**In all other cases it can't.**

Answer (score 24):

It CAN be null when Your application was updated from the market while it was in the memory and relaunched again after the update.
Maybe even If you will make update manually by Studio, or from .apk file, the same effect will be. Not sure, sorry.

I once updated application in Google Dev console and got several different NPE in Crashlitics in the lines with call getIntent(). It happened for all screens, where I used getIntent().getExtra() onCreate or even later in lifeCycle.

So... It looks ugly, but to avoid crashes I need to check intent for NULL value all the time I call getIntent and most of the times I call Finish() if the intent is null. But you can make other logic, ofc, for you purpose.

Comment: can you prove it with sample app? I tried to reproduce it, but without success.

Comment: @g4s8 I can't create the application, where the code will initialize any action which makes this crashes. Also, I am not sure that on every mobile phone it will be reproducible. So I suppose the best way is just to make checks.

Comment: omg, android as usual give us surprises. Thank's, for explanation!

Comment: I would like to update my notes: after I moved to Kotlin, the intent never brings me `null` value in Activities. At the same time I found out that any intent extras would be `null` after the activity is recreated after saved instance state. So, if you override saveInstantState(outState), put in bundle all extras you had in intent.extras.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `onSaveInstanceState()` callback method to avoid such situations, that will cause NPE due to null data from `getIntentExtra()`. Save the extra data to `outState` bundle and retrieve it on onCreate() callback by putting a null check to confirm if the activity was recreated or was a fresh one.

Example:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    extraData = savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_DATA);
} else {
    extraData = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA);
}
```