# app intent is not null on launch

Tags: java, android

On app launch intent is not null. I don't know why

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

/**
 * Views
 */
private ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     if (bundle == null)
        Log.d("***DEBUG****", "Intent was null");
    else
        Log.d("**** DEBUG ***", "Intent not null");
```

Close and reopen my application throw that intent is not null:
D/***DEBUG****: Intent not null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Activity.getIntent() ever return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856407/can-activity-getintent-ever-return-null)

Comment: The intent you get on launch is the intent the system uses to start you app. See the intent filter of your main activity in your Manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, by adding if(getIntent().getStringExtra("type")==null)