# Check if an intent data is null or not?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a streaming app which plays video in `ExoPlayer2`. I added an intent which opens the video in the external player but I want to check if the `getData()` is `empty/null` and if so, then show a toast or proceed with the `intent`.

My code:

```
      imgExternal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                if(getIntent().getData() == null) {
                    new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError("Sorry but there was an error retrieving the url!");
                } else {
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(listDirector.get(0).getStremURL()));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open In"));
                }

            }
        });
```

Now the problem is, my app thinks everything is null and showing me toast so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you define `getIntent()` ?

Comment: Only here, assuming it was correct.

Comment: Can you add the code from previous and current activity?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856407/can-activity-getintent-ever-return-null

Comment: Try TextUtils.isEmpty(getIntent().getData())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check

```
 if (listDirector.get(0).getStremURL() == null) {
        new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError("Sorry but there was an error retrieving the url!");
    } else {
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(listDirector.get(0).getStremURL()));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open In"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getIntent().getData()` try using `this.getIntent().getData()`

Comment: What difference should it make?