# Android getting result from an enum

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get the value of an enum that I pass in here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectBrush.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("Current brush", myFingerPainter.getBrush().name());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, BRUSH_REQUEST_CODE );
```

And I try and try and get it out in the second activity here:

```
  Paint.Cap brushStyle = Paint.Cap.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("Current brush"));
```

This is my logcat:

```
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26592
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.SelectBrush}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.SelectBrush.<init>(SelectBrush.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I also tried

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String brushString = bundle.getString("Current brush");
    Paint.Cap brushStyle = Paint.Cap.valueOf(brushString);
```

but I got a similar exception:

```
2020-10-31 11:55:38.921 28148-28148/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28148
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.SelectBrush}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.SelectBrush.<init>(SelectBrush.java:16)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I've read around and I think it's because the second activity believes that intent == null but I'm not sure why because I'm clearly creating it in the first class.

Comment: Your activity intent (`getIntent()`) is `null` which is weird. Are you sure that this is being called in or after `onCreate()`? There seems to be only two cases when it is `null`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541651/2410641

Comment: Try having a breakpoint at this `Paint.Cap brushStyle = Paint.Cap.valueOf(brushString);` you will get to know if the error is from intent or in assigning value for `brushStyle`

Answer (score 0):

Just had to put these lines in the onCreate method:

```
    String brushString = bundle.getString("Current brush");
    brushStyle = Paint.Cap.valueOf(brushString);
```

and this at the class level:

```
Paint.Cap brushStyle;
```