# Android Activity lifecycle problems

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, activity-lifecycle

I'm working on the project initially created by another developer. There is a root Activity (let's call it `CustomActivity`) with code below.

```
private static SomeOtherClass instance = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(null);

    if (!(Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() instanceof CustomExceptionHandler)) {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler());
    }

    // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes)
    if (!isTaskRoot() && getIntent().hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && null != getIntent().getAction()
            && getIntent().getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    instance = new SomeOtherClass();

    this.screen = new CustomFragment();
    this.getFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.content_frame, screen).commit();

    ...
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    this.instance = null;
    ...
}

static public SomeOtherClass getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}
```

`this.screen` has a button with `CustomActivity.getInstance().methodCall()` on tap. And one of beta testers said he just tapped that button and got crash with this method in stacktrace: `Attempt to invoke virtual method '...CustomActivity.getInstance().methodCall()' on a null object reference`.

I don't understand - how it's possible due to Activity lifecycle.

According to stacktrace, `onCreate` shouldn't be called after some previous `onDestroy`. Even if the last one can happen when we were in another Activity (and yep, this.screen is not nullified anywhere), but `this.screen` fragment can't be rendered without Activity recreation. Am I right?

P.S.: there is no more `instance` variable management at all and `SomeOtherClass` has no custom parent class (just default object).

P.P.S.: nope, device wasn't locked / app just launched. Tester worked with it, rotated phone to remove sim card, removed, rotated back and saw crash alert.

P.P.P.S: don't know why `null` in `super.onCreate()` but anyhow this Activity has no code to support saved states.

Comment: Is CustomActivity.getInstance().methodCall() inside fragment?

Comment: One thing that is not clear: Is this a base activity that is extended for others?

Comment: @DEADMC, yep, inside: `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { CustomActivity.getInstance().methodCall() });`

Comment: @theblitz, it's a root activity, launched from AndroidManifest.xml as main. No subclasses.