# Launcher activity open agains when the app is opened again from another app

Tags: android, back-stack, android-launcher

In my app, it starts with the Splash Screen. Then the user **login** and already reach to **Dashboard** **activity**. I **finish** the **Splash** and **Login activities** from the backstack.

But when the user open the app again from **Zapya**, the app load **new splash activity** on top of the **existing activity stack**. 
When the user tap on Back button, the **splash activity** disappears and the **Dashboard activity** display again.

According to my knowledge, the app should normally show the **topmost activity** when it already exists in the memory.

Please, suggest me is there anythings should I modify or configure?

Edit: This is a known bug and there is various ways to solve this problem. I've solved this problem by this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10598619/3229851).
You can also learn in the following post too.

[App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes)

Comment: you have to add singleTask in menifest tag

Comment: find more at: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Thanks, I already read it before. In your opinion, to which activity should I put "SingleTask" launchmode? I already put "SingleTask" launchmode to Login Activity.

Comment: have you try this property : android:excludeFromRecents="true" .....
             android:launchMode="singleTask".........
             android:taskAffinity="".........

Comment: @Steve.NayLinAung please show us the code.