# App.xaml.cs ctor is called when OnResume() should be called

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

If I navigate in my App and go back to the Android LaunchScreen with the HomeButton the OnSleep() Hook is called, which is fine. If I navigate back into the App using the Android TaskManager OnResume() is called.
If I navigate in my App with the Hardware BackButton then also OnSleep() is called which is fine, but if I navigate back into my app then the OnCreate Method in the MainActivity is called which recreated the App.

```
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        DisplayCrashReport();
        LoadApplication (new Gtue.Mobile.App ());
```

That should not happen. In the ctor of App.xaml I initialize stuff which only should be initialized once. I tried every LaunchMode for the MainAcitivity, nothing helped.

Is there a way to find out if the App was already initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `App` class extends from `Xamarin.Forms.Application` and the `Xamarin.Forms.Application` life cycle is bind with the `Activity` life cycle. You could find it in the [source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/FormsAppCompatActivity.cs#L319) :

```
async Task OnStateChanged()
{
    if (_application == null)
        return;

    if (_previousState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnCreate && _currentState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnStart)
        _application.SendStart();
    else if (_previousState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnStop && _currentState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnRestart)
        _application.SendResume();
    else if (_previousState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnPause && _currentState == AndroidApplicationLifecycleState.OnStop)
        await _application.SendSleepAsync();
}
```

So you just need to care about your `Activity`'s life cycle. When you touch the `HomeButton` your application don't remove the `MainActivity` from the task's stack and the `MainActivity` will be available when you re-enter the app, so it didn't execute the `OnCreate` method.

When you touch the `HomeButton` :

```
[0:] MainActivity OnPause
[0:] MainActivity OnStop
[0:] Forms App OnSleep
```

When you use  the Android `TaskManager` open your application :

```
[0:] MainActivity OnRestart
[0:] Forms App OnResume
[0:] MainActivity OnResume
```

---

But when you touch the hardware `BackButton`, the `MainActivity` will be removed from the   task's stack :

```
[0:] MainActivity OnPause
[0:] MainActivity OnStop
[0:] Forms App OnSleep
[0:] MainActivity OnDestroy
```

When the `MainActivity` is destoryed, your application will dispose resource and it including your  `Gtue.Mobile.App` instance. And you could see the [source code about OnDestroy() method](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/FormsAppCompatActivity.cs#L189) :

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    PopupManager.Unsubscribe(this);
    _platform?.Dispose();

    // call at the end to avoid race conditions with Platform dispose
    base.OnDestroy();
}
```

So the next time when you open your application, it is  necessary to recreated the `App` class. Actually, the `App` did only be initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when observing my App.xaml.cs constructor was being called when I was pressing the home button on my Android device and then clicking my app.

The well detailed answer above details the correct "anticipated behaviour", but this was **not** the case for me.

I was getting this kind of flow when using the home button or back button -

```
**On Debug Start**
MainActivity:OnCreate
XF:AppCtor
XF:OnStart
MainActivity:OnResume

**Press Home Button**
MainActivity:OnPause
XF:OnSleep

**Launch App via Click on App Icon**
MainActivity:OnCreate
XF:AppCtor
```

Searching eventually led me to -

[App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes)

Which in turn resulted in the following Xamarin code at the top of MainActivity OnCreate -

```
        if (!IsTaskRoot)
        {
            string action = Intent.Action;
            if (Intent.HasCategory(Android.Content.Intent.CategoryLauncher) &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Intent.Action) &&
                action == Android.Content.Intent.ActionMain)
            {
                Finish();
                return;
            }
        }
```

Which seems to solve the initial reload at least.

I also combined this with -

```
 LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
```

To stop some double activity shenanigans when clicking on a notification in notification screen.