# Android - running app from home screen vs running from task manager

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was wondering what is the difference between running android application from home screen (app icon) vs running it from task manager. Whenever I run it from the home screen I can see a splash screen for a short period of time, but after that I'm forwarded to the latest application state. The only difference when running it from task manager is that I don't see the splash screen. Is there any reasonable explanation behind that behavior? Sometimes when running application from home screen (app icon) it hangs on splash screen forever and I am unable to debug it in any way...

Comment: By `it hangs on splash screen forever and I am unable to debug it in any way`, it is normal, you just need to wait for Android to load your app. Xamarin.Android need mono to run its c# codes, the mono need JVM to load, so it need more time on splash screen than Native Android.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but returning to the app sometimes takes much more time than running it for the first time. And that is what bugs me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the lifecycle of Activity, like @FabriBertani has [said](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). You can see the lifecyle of Activity by its lifecycle methods:

`OnCreate` -> `OnStart` -> `OnResume` -> `OnPause` -> `OnStop` -> `OnDestroy`.

This is Activity's normal lifecycle.

---

There are several categories about from home screen and from task manager

### Running android application from home screen

- If the app has been running in your device recently, that means [Android Warm Start](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html).
- If the app hasn't been running in your device recently, that means Android Cold Start, so we usually use [splash screen](http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts) to deal with it.

### Running android application from task manager

- Your app is background and it has been killed by system, because of lack of resources.
- Your app is background and it hasn't been killed by system.

---

> Is there any reasonable explanation behind that behavior?

Yes. From your situation, it should be *Android Cold Start* and *not been killed*.

- Android Cold Start will create an App from zero, so it will call:`OnCreate` -> `OnStart` -> `OnResume`, before call Activity's `OnCreate`, it need create the environment which an App need, so you will see the splash screen. If we don't set our custom splash screen, you will see a white or black screen before you see the latest application state.
- Running app from task manager(not been killed) did create an App from zero. If you press *Home Button* instead of `Back Button`, your app will be in recent apps, it will call:`OnPause` -> `OnStop`, and when you run app from task manager, it will call:`OnRestart` -> `OnStart` -> `OnResume`, so you can't see the splash screen.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the app restarts rather then resumes when you start it from home screen. You can find the explanation this behavior here [App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes)

Comment: But It doesn't look like it restarts because it goes back to place where I left it. Or maybe Im just not understanding "restart" the way I should. For me restarting is when I start everything from beginning. So when I move from screen A to B then restarting should point me to screen A, not B. Thanks for the link though, It explains a lot.

Comment: Read this: [Android Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), try to understand all the Android lifecycle states, there is the answer to your question ;-)