# Resume activity after close it with back button

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an Player activity and Floating Player (service), after click on back button the Player Activity is close and the Floating Player is goes into action, when I click on the Floating Player I want to back to the Player Activity but with no run again the *onCreate* method.

I read a lot of solution in StackOver Flow, especially use the **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** 
and **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP** flags, or add **android:launchMode="singleTask"** / **android:launchMode="singleInstance"** to the Player Activity in the Manifest, but none of them not really work.

I would be happy if there is a real solution that make a single task to my Player Activity, and not reopen it from onCreate method.

Player Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWsIJ7UVxQs");
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate is running!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WindowPlayer.class));
    }
}
```

Floating player (service):

```
public class WindowPlayer extends Service {

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View contFloatingPlayer;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams contPlayerParams;
    private WebView webView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        initFloatingPlayer();

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/bWsIJ7UVxQs");

        webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                contFloatingPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.destroy();
                return false;
            }
        });

        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Intent backToStablePlayer = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        backToStablePlayer.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        startActivity(backToStablePlayer);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint({"ClickableViewAccessibility", "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "AddJavascriptInterface"})
    private void initFloatingPlayer() {
        int LAYOUT_FLAG;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }

        contPlayerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                532,
                300,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        contPlayerParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.START;
        contPlayerParams.x = 0;
        contPlayerParams.y = 100;

        contFloatingPlayer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, false);

        windowManager.addView(contFloatingPlayer, contPlayerParams);

        webView = contFloatingPlayer.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }
```

Note: I added Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent because it's intent from service, else it's crash.

Comment: when an activity is destroyed then you can't bring it back and not go through onCreate. Why is it a problem? What are you trying to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that when you click "back", the Activity's `finish()` method is called, the Activity is destroyed and so the next time you launch it it will go to `onCreate()`.
You can try this in MainActivity.class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();  // don't call the super
    goToHomeScreen();
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WindowPlayer.class));
}


public void goToHomeScreen() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

This way when you go back to your app, the Activity is not destroyed and it will not go to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Very nice Yoav!
In my real app i need to back to MainActivity.Class, and not to Home, how can i adjust it?

Comment: @Hila Isn't the player activity called MainActivity? Anyway, in your player activity, instead of goToHome() method you can launch your MainActivity like in Danial's answer.

Comment: In my question i added an example code.. in my real app there is A.class, B.class and C.class, how can i go back to B.class from C.class on your way in the answer

Comment: Only one solution working like a charm. App is minimized on back (as user expects but on resume finally it is not restarted). Thanks. Many other on stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/a/23220151/3826175 and do not work.

My modification with webview...

`public void onBackPressed() { if (webView.canGoBack()) { webView.goBack(); } else { Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(startMain); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
                    // to restore activity if there already running
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);  
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And In manifest of add for B activity

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: I tried it, not working, it's still run the onCreate method. the point is exactly what Yoav said, the onBack method is destroy the activity...