# Activity restarts instead of resuming

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

Steps:

1. Launch app using the launcher icon
2. Visit few pages / screens
3. Minimize app
4. Launch again from the launcher, **the last activity resumes**

Steps (issue):

1. Launch app using a deeplink from outside
2. Visit few pages / screens
3. Minimize app
4. Launch again from the launcher, **the launch activity starts over the previous activity**

**How can we ensure that the current running activity is resumed when app is opened using launcher ?**

possibly related: [App restarts rather than resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545889/app-restarts-rather-than-resumes/43345092)

The app in question is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fun.drawguess
and is deeplinked with urls starting https://drawguess.fun

built using the svg twa example: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa

Comment: Can you confirm the Chrome version installed?

Comment: Its Chrome 81.04 on Android 10