# App restart while click on app icon

Tags: android

We are facing issue while installing app first time.

Here is the steps to reproduce this issue

1. Install the app
2. Click open button
3. Open app
4. Press device home button
5. Click on app icon
6. App restarted

but if we click on done button after install the app then everthing is working perfect.

Comment: post your code for `onStop()`, `onStart` of the relevant activity here.

Comment: And what is the issue ?

Comment: App restarted while click on app icon when the app is background (when you press device home button and click again on app icon)but as per my concern is that app should not restarted.

Comment: please check whether app restarts on pressing home button on particular Activity or on every activity

Comment: Already checked app restarts on  every activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App completely restarting when launched by icon press in launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126511/app-completely-restarting-when-launched-by-icon-press-in-launcher)

Answer (score 1):

> Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Instant Run

Comment: Instant run is not the solution because we need to send apk to user

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys! I figured out this issue. Actually this is the bug of android launch. This is not happened only for my app, This issue is occured on whstapp also or we can say that every android app. Basically after install the app there is two option one for done and second for open. If we pressed done button then everthing will work perfect but in case of open app will restart first time or we can say that app restarted untill the user kill the app.